# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, typescript

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Error Occurs On The script tag as Exception parsing document

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing a closing tag somewhere. I have no idea what you have in the HTML template, unless you post the complete code.

Comment: This is an complete code i am just div tag inside body  that has map in it....nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf templates are valid XML, so inside an attribute you need to use & instead of &.

Comment: Thymeleaf templates are valid XML, so inside an attribute you need to use &amp instead of &.